# OWASP Zap Exclude URLS

Tags: zap

I am trying to add numbers of URLs to exclude from proxy (ZAP), i don't understand how to add multiple URLs in code to exclude.

Example :

String excludeProxy = "^((?!.*google.*).*)$";

I want to exclude other URLs like

1. [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)
2. [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com)
3. [www.twitter.com](http://www.twitter.com)
4. [www.linkedin.com](http://www.linkedin.com)

How to generate or define the single variable that can add these all URLs to exclude.

Comment: How are you running and controlling ZAP? The answer will be different if you are using the desktop vs the Automation Framework vs the API etc..